# Issues when updating iOS app from wildcard to explicit app ID?

Tags: iphone, ios

We have an app in the store right now that was shipped with a wildcard app ID.

The update that is now pending approval was created with an explicit app ID, to enable push notifications.

We've noticed the following issue during ad hoc testing of the update: if we delete the app-store version from our iPhones, and then install the ad-hoc update, everything is fine. If, however, we leave the app-store version running in the background, and install the ad-hoc update over it, the updated version installs but fails to start up. We suspect that this has to do with the ID change.

If this problem is specific to ad hoc installs, then it is not a worry for us, but we are concerned that existing users will encounter this problem when doing the real upgrade from the app store.

Has anyone seen installation issues after upgrading from a wildcard-ID app to an explicit-ID version?

Comment: Have you tried killing the App Store version then installing the new version?

Comment: Yes, and that works. My concern is not about whether we can get the app installed ourselves, but what will happen when users upgrade from the app store, without killing the previous version.

Comment: Any wisdeom to share meanwhile? Did it work well?